# How to get maximum possible file size in Android

Tags: android, filesystems, android-storage

I would like to get maximum possible file size, which can be stored.
Yes, It's limited by filesystem (FAT32=4GB, FAT16=2GB, ext4=16TB), but Is there any limit by Android?

Input (String or URI): File path (/storage/...) or URI
Output (long): size in bytes

Thank you!

Comment: Android uses ext4 filesystem so, i guess the limit is 16 TB

Comment: And what about when user mounts SDcard with FAT32?

Comment: then i guess the sdcard follows it's FAT32 limit that is 4GB

Comment: SDcard can be FAT16, FAT32, NTFS, ext4, ...

Comment: then the sdcard will follow the limit of whatever filesystem it is using....i guess...

Comment: Yes and question was, how can I get file system information :)

Comment: Use any terminal app and type mount to know filesystem of every partition

Comment: No Android API is available to get this information?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
FileSystem filesystem = FileSystems.getDefault();

    for (FileStore store : filesystem.getFileStores()) {
        Log.d("TEST", "onCreate: "+store.toString() + " : " + store.type() +"\n");
    }
```

It will print all the filestores with their filesystem type

The output will be like this :

[image: Logcat scrren shot]

**Note :**  It is just a small part of the output.

Documentation links :

[FileSystems - getDefault](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/file/FileSystems#public-methods_1)

[FileSystem - getFileStores](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/file/FileSystem#getFileStores())

[FileStore - type](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/file/FileStore#type())

Comment: Thank you. Do you know what is size limit for "fuse" or "sdcardfs"?

Comment: fuse is userspace filesystem framework (Api) and sdcardfs is also a virtual filesystem , both can emulate any filesystem (usually they emulate FAT32). To understand these two , i would suggest you read this : https://www.xda-developers.com/diving-into-sdcardfs-how-googles-fuse-replacement-will-reduce-io-overhead/

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. I still cannot determine maximum file size :-(

Comment: I think it's clear that android internal storage uses ext4 and therefore the limit is 16TB which we are not going to cross for now.

Comment: I still don't understand how can I get max file size for "fuse" or "sdcardfs" virtual file systems?

Comment: Example: what is the max. file size of: `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data (/data/media) : sdcardfs` and of `/storage/6134-3761 (/dev/fuse) : fuse` ? The first is `internal storage`, second is `SDCard`.

Comment: Not sure but , internal storage - ext4 - 16TB file limit and SDCard - FAT32 - 4GB file limit.

Comment: SDcard could be formatted like NTFS, FAT16/32, ext4 etc. Not only FAT32.